# Problem with insert an image in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, floats, diagrams

I have a problem with floating pictures. The system places it anywhere, but I want after some text. I had to use different ways to place images, but no result.
My code is:

```
\documentclass[
% twocolumn,
]{ceurart}

\usepackage{float}

....
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{ranking.png}
\caption{Diagram of the functionality of online platforms}
\label{ris:ranking}
\end{figure}
```

In the line of code with key `[h]` I have a message:

> `Latex3 error: the key ‘cas/fig/h’ is unknown and is being ignored.`

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! Where is available `ceurart` document class? Using `article` your errors cant be reproduced.

Comment: Here is [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BmrOFfUtgep0LrYNBvjyGaSOh_5pNZOj/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

The class is based on `cas-common` and has a key-value system for options to `figure` and `table`.

```
\documentclass[
% twocolumn,
]{ceurart}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[width=13cm,pos=htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\figwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Diagram of the functionality of online platforms}
\label{ris:ranking}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You should probably set `width` in terms of `\columnwidth`.

Answer (score 0):

The document class `ceurart` doesn't allow the use of placement options. The following MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{ceurart}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}  % <--- ceurart doesn't allow the use of placement options
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Diagram of the functionality of online platforms}
\label{ris:ranking}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I understand that, but this is the class we need to work with. Can I change the permissions in this class?

Comment: If you write article for journal, which use this document class, any changes to it are not allowed.  This class care for figure placement as publisher like to have. For any changes, if you persist to do so, please ask author of classes, how to do this.

Comment: Yes, it's true. It is the document class for a journal. Thank you for your help. I will ask the creators.

Comment: Again, document class care about floats placement. It has built in positioning options (htbp), so you not need to redefine anything. With redefining you will only  make problems to publisher.

Comment: @Zarko No, the class *does* allow placement options.

Comment: as far as >I see. it is based on `scrartcl` . However, I'm not familiar with it, so may you are right.